# SKlearn: Gaussian Process Regression Prediction is Same for any Input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, gaussian

I am testing Gaussian Process Regression using Sklearn but my GP predictions after fitting the date are same everywhere. Is there something I am missing?

````py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor

y=[  60.3295131,    53.56137623,    6.18362039,   43.27383624,   73.63256713]

x=[[ 0.02690405, -0.76987722],
 [ 0.51031994, -0.46978989],
 [-1.4756594,   2.15417603],
 [ 0.02674444,  0.6513043 ],
 [ 0.31203479,  0.95269764]]

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(
            kernel=Matern(nu=2.5),
            alpha=1e-6,
            normalize_y=True,
            n_restarts_optimizer=5,
            random_state=125,
        )

gp.fit(x, y)

print(gp.predict([(-1.3,1.54),(.3,.54)]))

print(gp.predict([(3111,.54)])) ```
````

Comment: Can you add more data? It seems that the GP gives a blanket prediction equal to the mean of the y array possibly because it didn't have enough data to train or the data is not good enough.

Comment: thats the only data I have. How to determine if the data is not good enough?

Comment: It depends on what you trying to solve. If you want to predict accurately for new data then with train test split you'll be able to quantify that. If you want to understand a process then maybe a more interpretable algorithm such as regression may help especially with so few data points

Comment: It's been some time but just in case here's another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017587/why-my-gaussianprocessregressor-model-returns-constant-predictions) where adding the white kernel to account for the noise helped.

Comment: @balleveryday let me check this in this week and confirm, but as far as i know it is a known issue and as I remember an issue was already opened in GitHub on this.