# Why my GaussianProcessRegressor model returns Constant predictions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, gaussian

I'm using GaussianProcessregressor from Sklearn library to make predictions. My X_train is a 2D array containing x and y coordinates ,and y_train is a vector of temperatures in Fahrenheit( values are between 30 and  60 F and the mean value is 42F), This is the model :

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
length_scale_param=1.9
length_scale_bounds_param=(1e-05, 100000.0)
nu_param=2.5
matern=Matern(length_scale=length_scale_param, length_scale_bounds=length_scale_bounds_param, nu=nu_param)
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=matern,normalize_y=True)
```

I'm setting normalize_y to True to get a prior mean that is equal to the actual mean of my data which is 42 instead of the default one which is equal to 0.

I'm making predictions on a 2D grid:

```
rx, ry = np.arange(min(X[:,0]),max(X[:,0]),0.01), np.arange(min(X[:,1]),max(X[:,1]),0.01)
gx, gy = np.meshgrid(rx, ry)
X_2D = np.c_[gx.ravel(), gy.ravel()]
```

I get the following surface plot :

[image]

As you can see in this plot , predictions are constant and are always equal to the mean.

I tried  to change the kernel and the kernel parameters but I keep having the same problem.

I tried also to set the optimizer to None (instead of the default optimizer which is used to optimize the parameters of the kernel by maximizing the log-marginal likelihood, when optimizer=None the initial parameters of the kernel  are kept fixed), I get the following result:

[image]

but here i had to implement a grid search to better choose the initial parameters of the kernel (which is time consuming given the size of my dataset).

I guess that in the first case the optimizer is not working correctly for some reason.

Any suggestions?

This is my X_train :

```
array([[-0.07175708, -0.04827261],
       [ 0.20393194,  0.20058493],
       [ 0.3603364 ,  0.07715549],
       [ 0.17013275,  0.06315295],
       [ 0.09156826, -0.02107808],
       [-0.14215737,  0.01280404],
       [ 0.06130448, -0.13786868],
       [ 0.2392198 ,  0.1786702 ],
       [ 0.06257225, -0.00621065],
       [ 0.32712505,  0.25779511],
       [ 0.29779007, -0.08769269],
       [-0.14826638, -0.0370103 ],
       [ 0.41075394, -0.1100057 ],
       [ 0.34963454,  0.20687578],
       [ 0.4809849 , -0.20138262],
       [-0.19123097, -0.06000154],
       [-0.0335645 , -0.02598649],
       [ 0.47650189, -0.11234306],
       [ 0.35300743, -0.12135059],
       [ 0.15285929,  0.26463927],
       [ 0.25162424,  0.26882754],
       [-0.12485825, -0.02486853],
       [ 0.46869993,  0.01067606],
       [ 0.46410817, -0.17518689],
       [ 0.36756061,  0.1329964 ],
       [ 0.41387258,  0.06388724],
       [ 0.24489864,  0.1566825 ],
       [ 0.34972446,  0.22217119],
       [-0.10762011, -0.24574283],
       [ 0.43273621,  0.0916413 ],
       [ 0.39971044,  0.19253515],
       [ 0.35053608, -0.17008844],
       [ 0.02222162, -0.21485839],
       [ 0.30105785,  0.23001327],
       [ 0.05772036,  0.06681724],
       [-0.43849245,  0.1222685 ],
       [ 0.09869866,  0.02871409],
       [ 0.2033424 ,  0.1212952 ],
       [ 0.27993967,  0.22868547],
       [ 0.15177833,  0.23868958],
       [-0.21212757, -0.11004732],
       [ 0.44694002,  0.05587976],
       [ 0.21171764, -0.11056078],
       [ 0.02776326, -0.28147262],
       [ 0.44578859, -0.0587219 ],
       [ 0.29600242,  0.06741206],
       [ 0.27655553,  0.27980429],
       [ 0.20468395,  0.19475542],
       [ 0.38154889,  0.04721793],
       [ 0.01957093, -0.26531009],
       [ 0.05286766,  0.02185995],
       [ 0.3056768 ,  0.22414755],
       [ 0.16743847,  0.16073349],
       [ 0.05609711,  0.07843347],
       [ 0.41648273,  0.17360153],
       [ 0.18231324,  0.26745677],
       [ 0.14966242,  0.10538568],
       [ 0.02549186, -0.01958948],
       [-0.0352719 , -0.02737327],
       [ 0.16600666,  0.07729444],
       [-0.12564782, -0.12275318],
       [ 0.37777642,  0.24001348],
       [-0.27694849,  0.00378039],
       [ 0.44526109,  0.12339138],
       [ 0.3685266 , -0.09494673],
       [-0.1995266 , -0.02930646],
       [-0.12903661, -0.10557621],
       [ 0.1709348 , -0.01605571],
       [ 0.26204141,  0.00431368],
       [-0.07393948,  0.00719171],
       [ 0.25412697, -0.13938606],
       [ 0.21738421, -0.05103692],
       [-0.46865246,  0.11646383],
       [ 0.10859337, -0.24675289],
       [ 0.31137355, -0.01317134],
       [-0.32543566,  0.01758948],
       [ 0.1353631 ,  0.09693234],
       [ 0.22925417, -0.08178113],
       [ 0.19070138,  0.07616783],
       [ 0.35729195,  0.16464414],
       [-0.18762354, -0.1619709 ],
       [ 0.38675886, -0.05008602],
       [ 0.40249564,  0.18417801],
       [-0.26503112, -0.07816367],
       [-0.5       ,  0.1422947 ],
       [ 0.23234044,  0.15395552],
       [ 0.41635281,  0.28778189],
       [-0.00504366, -0.05262536],
       [-0.23091464, -0.15458275],
       [ 0.31935293,  0.15605484],
       [ 0.24921385, -0.05876454],
       [-0.39930397,  0.28697901],
       [ 0.05286766,  0.02185995],
       [ 0.12650071,  0.08691902],
       [-0.41328647,  0.11521126],
       [-0.02549319, -0.21558453],
       [ 0.38447761,  0.18176482],
       [-0.49606913,  0.04726729],
       [ 0.26226766,  0.09769927],
       [ 0.37959486,  0.16020508],
       [ 0.39688515,  0.28609912],
       [-0.21750272, -0.05315777],
       [-0.16742417,  0.31337447],
       [ 0.35049142,  0.16397509],
       [ 0.09923472, -0.05051281],
       [ 0.39039074, -0.00533958],
       [ 0.34954183,  0.070406  ],
       [-0.03250529, -0.09619029],
       [-0.02553826, -0.21512205],
       [ 0.32684651, -0.00806486],
       [-0.035674  , -0.10242529],
       [ 0.3840333 ,  0.19410431],
       [ 0.34593852,  0.03607444],
       [ 0.49294163, -0.19796509],
       [ 0.00115703, -0.10888053],
       [ 0.38564422, -0.05671838],
       [ 0.38633704,  0.15706933],
       [ 0.41442829,  0.07688914],
       [ 0.00182541, -0.18194074],
       [ 0.19541211,  0.19816678],
       [ 0.21203674,  0.03370675],
       [ 0.22605457, -0.0154448 ],
       [ 0.32304629,  0.04642338],
       [ 0.40787352,  0.12211336],
       [ 0.06104107, -0.26257386],
       [ 0.14581334,  0.17887325],
       [ 0.19600414, -0.0199909 ],
       [-0.11808573,  0.04732613],
       [ 0.42421385, -0.00113821],
       [ 0.23317682,  0.05307291],
       [ 0.07724509, -0.20107056],
       [ 0.05623529, -0.31337447],
       [-0.1586227 ,  0.29292413],
       [ 0.10418996,  0.01066445],
       [ 0.41380266, -0.07030375],
       [ 0.24685584,  0.10346794],
       [ 0.10166612,  0.13223216],
       [ 0.21053369,  0.02633374],
       [-0.35277745,  0.27849323],
       [-0.20414733, -0.0153229 ],
       [-0.26929086, -0.19337318],
       [ 0.26345883, -0.05154861],
       [ 0.13480402,  0.09701327],
       [ 0.2934898 ,  0.07205294],
       [-0.00824799,  0.03543839],
       [ 0.43831267,  0.21319967]])
```

And this is Y_train :

```
array([[39.9],
       [45.7],
       [46.1],
       [42.5],
       [43.5],
       [39.7],
       [42.9],
       [45.8],
       [42.6],
       [44.2],
       [45.2],
       [23.4],
       [49.3],
       [45. ],
       [48.6],
       [41.1],
       [39.9],
       [48.3],
       [48.5],
       [46.1],
       [45.5],
       [28.7],
       [49.1],
       [48.2],
       [44.2],
       [45.3],
       [44.9],
       [45.1],
       [43.3],
       [46.5],
       [45.3],
       [48.3],
       [43.4],
       [45.3],
       [41.9],
       [37.5],
       [41.9],
       [47.3],
       [45.3],
       [46.3],
       [36.7],
       [47.1],
       [46.1],
       [46.8],
       [49.3],
       [45.9],
       [46. ],
       [45.9],
       [44.4],
       [45. ],
       [37.7],
       [45.2],
       [46. ],
       [42.8],
       [45.2],
       [47.7],
       [45.3],
       [39. ],
       [39. ],
       [43.6],
       [26.3],
       [46.2],
       [40.4],
       [46.6],
       [48.4],
       [42.4],
       [36.6],
       [44.9],
       [43.5],
       [42.3],
       [46.4],
       [45.8],
       [39.4],
       [44.3],
       [45.2],
       [40.8],
       [45.7],
       [45.4],
       [42.9],
       [44.8],
       [30.4],
       [47.1],
       [44.7],
       [38.4],
       [38.2],
       [45.3],
       [45. ],
       [38.1],
       [42.5],
       [45.4],
       [44.6],
       [41.1],
       [38.2],
       [45.3],
       [40.2],
       [41.5],
       [48. ],
       [36.1],
       [44.7],
       [46.8],
       [45.6],
       [40.6],
       [43.5],
       [44.8],
       [42.6],
       [44.9],
       [43.2],
       [40.6],
       [41.5],
       [46. ],
       [41.7],
       [48.7],
       [49.6],
       [48.4],
       [41.3],
       [47.8],
       [47.3],
       [46.2],
       [43.8],
       [46.2],
       [44.9],
       [46.1],
       [44.5],
       [46.3],
       [43.2],
       [46.1],
       [44.1],
       [40. ],
       [47.3],
       [41.4],
       [46. ],
       [46. ],
       [44.4],
       [40.7],
       [44.5],
       [45.2],
       [43.9],
       [44.1],
       [42.9],
       [42.4],
       [40.6],
       [42.7],
       [45.2],
       [45. ],
       [42.4],
       [46. ]])
```

Comment: Could you share the data so we can recreate the predictions?

Comment: I added some data points to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Given the data above the model will need a noise term to improve performance. I get predictions that differ from the mean by adding the white kernel to the matern. Below is comparison of the two:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern, WhiteKernel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

length_scale_param=1.9
length_scale_bounds_param=(1e-05, 100000.0)
nu_param=2.5
matern=Matern(length_scale=length_scale_param,
              length_scale_bounds=length_scale_bounds_param,nu=nu_param)
kernel = matern + WhiteKernel()
gpr_0 = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=matern,normalize_y=True,
                                 n_restarts_optimizer=0)
gpr_1 =  GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,normalize_y=True,
                                  n_restarts_optimizer=0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33,
                                                    random_state=42)

gpr_0.fit(X_train,y_train)
gpr_1.fit(X_train,y_train)                                                    

y_pred_0 = gpr_0.predict(X_test)
y_pred_1 = gpr_1.predict(X_test)

plt.scatter(y_test,y_pred_0,label='matern only')
plt.scatter(y_test,y_pred_1,label='matern + noise kernel')
plt.plot(np.arange(y.min(),y.max(),1),np.arange(y.min(),y.max(),1),'--',
         color='grey')
plt.xlabel('y_test')
plt.xlabel('y_pred')
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I would also suggest setting the `n_restarts_optimizer=9` to allow for more iterations. The default is `n_restarts_optimizer=0` and that only allows for one iteration.

Comment: Thank you, adding the whitekernel helped. Here i'm using the MSE to evaluate the model. When i set `nu=2.5` I get MSE=6.39 but when I set `nu=0.1` I get MSE=3.72. Is the nu parameter also optimized during the training phase ? Given the documentation nu controls the smoothness of the function and it usually takes values in [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, inf]. How can I choose the best value for the nu parameter that gives the best MSE score !

Comment: Do you get that sort of improvement on the test set? Maybe a smaller `nu` result to overfitting? According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Matern.html) `nu` is not optimised.

Comment: Your question of choosing the values for a hyper-parameter is the problem of  [model selection](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf). For a start I would suggest trying [gridsearchcv](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938819/optimise-custom-gaussian-processes-kernel-in-scikit-using-gridsearch).

Comment: Yes I got that improvement on the test set, I'm using a grid search to pick the best `nu`. According to some literature reviews the Matern kernel is the  most suitable one for regression problems. Maybe, I would rather implement a grid search to both selecting the kernel type and its parameters. Thank you I'll check the documentation.